# Can't ssh localhost within docker

Tags: docker, ssh

I build docker image with ssh enabled by such dockerfile: `docker build -t debian-ssh:v00 .`

```
From debian
WORKDIR /
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server sudo
RUN sed -i "s/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "root:123456" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root   ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
# RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN mkdir /run/sshd
# RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

After building, I start container by `docker run -d --name ssh00 debian-ssh00`. Then `docker exec -it ssh00 bash` -> `ssh localhost`, it give me message:

```
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:sF5hbx2GTw/Fq3QhQyRJ2+YNwBFPy/Iu5c8PtgpU/ok.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password:
root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I type password `123456` above. Why this happended?

I use docker for windows with latest version, i.e. docker engine v20.10.2 but still using backend hyper-V

Update:
There was an official tutorial about [Dockerize an SSH service](https://web.archive.org/web/20200307091028/https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) in the year 2020. But now [it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) is discouraged.

Comment: I agree: ssh to a container is not a good practice. But in the context of your original question, the answer is still of interest to debug ssh connexion issue in general.

Comment: @Vonc why *ssh to a container* is not a good practice?

Comment: It has always been considered as an anti-pattern, as it widens the attack surface of your container. It opens one more access entry, which is most often *not* needed (since you have `docker exec`). See https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/ or https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh#preamble. On the anti-pattern side: https://codefresh.io/containers/docker-anti-patterns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, once in your Docker bash session, try and change the root password (again) with the [`passwd` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html): it will ask you for your old password (the one you put in Dockerfile).
That way, you can double check the default container account (here `root`) does indeed have the password '123456'.

Second, try the same ssh command in verbose mode, to see if any clues are apparent:

```
ssh -vv localhost
```

If the password for root is correct, then check you [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79451/7490): if it has `PermitRootLogin no`, it would disallow any root session.

If this works, you would need to modify your Dockerfile in order to amend the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The [OP Spaceship222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7390103/spaceship222) confirms [in the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51469014#51469014):

> `RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config` will make debian-based container work

Comment: I try both but it still fails. I have updated the result.

Comment: `passwd` only asks for new password.

Comment: @Spaceship222 "passwd only asks for new password": OK, at least it gives you the occasion to enter a simple one and test it right away. Is the password actually '123456', or is it one with more complex possibly special characters?

Comment: After entering new password ”123456“, it still fails to `ssh localhost`

Comment: @Spaceship222 OK, I just edited the answer with an additional parameter for you to check.

Comment: `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i "PermitRootLogin"` outputs `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".`

Comment: @Spaceship222 Can you try and set it to `PermitRootLogin yes`, for testing?

Comment: it still fails after append `PermitRootLogin yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227882/discussion-between-vonc-and-spaceship222).

Answer (score 1):

This is purely configuration of sshd daemon issue. By default for security reasons access to root account with password authentication is disabled so you have two options:

1. Change the configuration of the ssh daemon and allow password authentication for root account (NOTE there is a reason why we don't allow root access by default so I would suggest you leave it this way)
2. Set up public/private key and set up authorized_keys file for root account in this context. I'm not sure how do you want to use this container and in general you should simply add your public key in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file and you' ll be fine.

For your particular case if you really want to solve your problem with

```
ssh localhost
```

You can add one line to your Dockerfile which generates a public/private keypair and adds it to your authorized_keys for root user OR you can run this command after you first login using docker exec command.

Your altered Dockerfile (public/private key version)

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server sudo
RUN sed -i "s/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "root:123456" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root   ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
# RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N "" && cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub>/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN mkdir /run/sshd
# RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

OR simply run this command in container after you execute into bash

```
 ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N "" && cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub>/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

UPDATE:
You are using sed but sed isn't available so as for starter you need to add sed with apt and if you want to build this container with PermitRootLogin yes you need to use sed to change the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
Your altered Dockerfile (root password login allowed)

```
FROM Debian
WORKDIR /
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server sudo sed
RUN sed -i "s/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sed -i "s/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "root:123456" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root   ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
# RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
# RUN ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN mkdir /run/sshd
# RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I hope this solves your problem fully.

Comment: I know this way. But if you want ssh to container from outside,  you have to append public key to authorized_keys for each new host outside.

Comment: I have updated Dockerfile ready to build your container with the PermitRootLogin yes value so you have above two Dockerfiles one with public/private key authentication and second with password authentication.